# How to filter the ListEntitiesAsync method from Azure Functions External Table binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions, external-tables

I successfully implemented the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-table) to get an Azure Function working with a Google Drive Spreadsheet. The sample code returns all the items in the file. I want to return a single row by applying a fliter. Is it possible? I tested the following code and it's not working:

```
`Query query = Query.Parse("$filter=Id eq 5");
var list = await inputTable.ListEntitiesAsync(query);`
```

However, this other code works, as it returns only the first 50 items:

```
`Query query = Query.Parse("$top=50");
var list = await inputTable.ListEntitiesAsync(query);`
```

Perhaps filtering is not implemented yet? I am aware that External Tables are Experimental, so if it's not possible, it is OK, and then I can do a workaround.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not appear anything but “$top” has been implemented with Google Sheets query. You can see details here - the operation the Functions is exposing here is List Rows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/googlesheet/#Get_rows

Comment: Thank you. While I already knew about `$top`, the link that you suggested mentioned the `$skip` parameter. Combining the power of both, I could finally accomplish my goal. For instance, in order to retrieve ID 4501, I simply used  `Query query = Query.Parse("$skip=4500&$top=1");` (of course, it requires all previous IDs to exist).